# Is crossveinless in Drosophila melanogaster example of condition mutant or phenocarpy?

Tags: molecular-biology, mutations, drosophila

This is the original question -
Ques - A researcher exposed Drosophila larvae to 37°C during their growth. One of the adult flies that emerged had a crossveinless phenotype. When this crossveinless fly was crossed to a known crossveinless mutant fly all the progeny had normal phenotype. The options had both condition mutant and phenocopy.
What is the difference between condition mutant and phenocopy?
Any specific points I can use differentiate between them in such a question?